# Store image from webcam in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to save captured image in a folder from webcam. My code captures image only but how can I store it in a folder. This is my first time to do this. If anyone mention that it will be helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>WebcamJS Test Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    h2, h3 { margin-top:0; }
    form { margin-top: 15px; }
    form > input { margin-right: 15px; }
    #results { float:right; margin:20px; padding:20px; border:1px solid; background:#ccc; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results">Captured image will appear here...</div>

<h1>WebcamJS Test Page</h1>
<h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>

<div id="my_camera"></div>

<!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.min.js"></script>

<!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
</script>

<!-- A button for taking snaps -->
<form>
    <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
</form>

<!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
                '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just ajax up `data_uri` then base64 decode it and store it in a folder.

Comment: in your function take_snapshot() use ajax call inside and store it through php side using file upload function

Comment: Actually a quick look at the docs, you have `Webcam.upload()`: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md#api-reference | https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md#submitting-images-to-a-server